# Calculating a fine and then and additional fine for every hour after

Tags: java

I need to calculate a fine for a parking meter. The fine is $25.00 for the first hour, or any part thereof, that the car is illegally parked. An additional $10.00 will be added for every additional hour, or part thereof, that the car is illegally parked. I can't figure out how to calculate each additional hour.

What I have so far:

```
if(car.getMinutesParked()-meter.getminutesPurchased()<=60)
{
    totalFine = FINE;
}   
else if(car.getMinutesParked()-meter.getminutesPurchased()>60)
{
    totalFine = FINE + (ADDITIONAL_FINE)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final int delta = car.getMinutesParked() - meter.getminutesPurchased();
if (delta > 0) {
    totalFine = FINE + (delta / 60)*ADDITIONAL_FINE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about it logically. You just typed out in words what needs to be done, so take a second to sit back and figure out how to translate that to code. Continuing with your format:

```
int totalFine = 0;
int totalTime = car.getMinutesParked();

if(totalTime - meter.getMinutesPurchased() <= 60){
       totalFine = FINE;
}
else{
       totalFine = FINE;                        // add fine for first hour
       totalTime = totalTime - 60;              // remove that first hour for our total time

       // add our initial fine + (number of additional hours * fee per additional hour)
       totalFine = totalFine + ((totalTime / 60) * ADDITIONAL_FINE);
}
```

There are ways to simplify the formatting of the code, but I figured it would be better to kind of show what is gong on step by step

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean firstHour = true;
int minutes = car.getMinutesParked() - meter.getMinutesPurchased();
int fineDollars = 0;
while (minutes > 0) {
    if (firstHour) fineDollars += 25;
    else fineDollars += 10;
    firstHour = false;
    minutes -= 60;
}
```